# MBUF full, what's the best thing to do?

Tags: freebsd

I noticed today that the MBUF usage has hit its limit.
Apparently the site I'm running under pfsense is having some troubles too, I'd like to know if it would be safe to just

> sysctl kern.ipc.nmbclusters=65536

I wouldn't like to reboot the server, is it safe (or useful) to do it via pfsense shell?

thanks you very much

```
2.0-RELEASE (amd64) 
built on Tue Sep 13 17:05:32 EDT 2011 

State table size    35573/550000
MBUF Usage    25600/25600
CPU usage 2%
Memory usage 17% (2GB)
Swap 0%
CPU: Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5450 @ 3.00GHz
```

Comment: I don't see a programming question here. Perhaps this should be moved to [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/)?

Answer (score 2):

It should be ok.

Keep in mind that each mbuf-cluster is 2KB of size, besides each of them needs mbuf which is 256 bytes long. This can be used to calculate memory usage after raising nmbclusters (65535 * 2K + 65535 * 256, etc).

Comment: Your calculation is helpful (65535 * 2304). netstat -mm command automatically shows all these statistics (# of 2k, 4K, 16K clusters and size of the clusters (2304, 4352, 16640) etc.